# Why does {{ user.groups }} always show auth.Group.None

Tags: python, django

When I use `{{ user.groups }}` in my template, I always get `auth.Group.None`, even though the user is logged in and is part of a group.

I can access the groups from the code with `request.user.groups.all()`, but I need an "always works" version in my templates.

Answer (score 9):

Is exactly what you just asked.

On Django the connection between User and Group is a Many2Many. So if you want to access the groups on the user you have to use

```
User.groups.all()
```

Or

```
User.groups.filter()
User.groups.get()
```

So you can realize that if you want to access group by user you need to do a queryset first.

If you want to print every group of that user you should use

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to show just a specific group you should create a separated function, you will not be able to do it just with Django template.